# enter keys to focus next but not on jbutton

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

Is it possible if we make enter key to set focus next of component? but if focused on jbutton, so enter key does firing jbutton? 
Please help me.
I'm sorry if my language is bad, I can't speak english very well. I'm sorry. But, please help me.

I use this code to set focus next of component.

```
Set<AWTKeyStroke> set = new HashSet<AWTKeyStroke>(KeyboardFocusManager
    .getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().getDefaultFocusTraversalKeys(
        KeyboardFocusManager.FORWARD_TRAVERSAL_KEYS));
set.add(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ENTER"));
KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().setDefaultFocusTraversalKeys(
    KeyboardFocusManager.FORWARD_TRAVERSAL_KEYS, set);
```

and I use this code to set enter key to firing jbutton

```
UIManager.put("Button.defaultButtonFollowsFocus", Boolean.TRUE);
```

But firing jbutton with enter key not work...

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: By the way.  Is this actually different to your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19477351/418556)?  Please add an upper case letter at the start of sentences.  Also use a capital for the word I, and abbreviations and acronyms like JEE or WAR.  This makes it easier for people to understand and help.

Comment: Please help yourself by following the advice in my first comment.  Please..

Comment: I've edited my question. I'm sorry if that to bad. I did ask about that, but I haven't answer. I think my question is wrong, I use google translate for help my question in English language. I can't speak English very well. just it I can write the question. i hope you understand my condition.

Comment: Yes it's good you corrected the upper case letters, but my first comment was about posting an SSCCE.  If there is anything in the linked document on the SSCCE that you don't understand, ask me, since I am in a good position to explain (I wrote it).

Comment: I've read it, but I do not understand my mistake in the question above. please explain my mistakes

Comment: Well of S-SC-C-E it is only S, BUT not SC, not C and definitely not an E.  If you do not understand what the SSCCE document says, be specific about what you do not understand.  Don't expect me to spoon-feed you.

Comment: I don't understand about how to set key type to focusnext() jcomponent on java, usually we use TAB key to this, but I want make it with Enter Key and also I want to set Enter Key to get ActionPerformed of Jbutton. nah, i don't understant how to make like that

Comment: How about taking the button you do not want focus to fall upon and doing `setFocusable(false)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note `Enter` key is commonly intended to fire an `ActionEvent` but not a `FocusEvent`. For instance if you set an `ActionListener` to a `JTextField` when you press `Enter` key it will dispatch an `ActionEvent`.

So if you set the behavior of `Enter` key pressed using `KeyboardFocusManager` you'll be overriding this feature for all `Windows` and `Components`:

[KeyboarFocusManager.setDefaultFocusTraversalKeys()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/KeyboardFocusManager.html#setDefaultFocusTraversalKeys%28int,%20java.util.Set%29):

> Sets the default focus traversal keys for a given traversal operation.
>   This traversal key `Set` will be in effect on **all** `Windows` that have no
>   such `Set` of their own explicitly defined. This `Set` will also be
>   inherited, recursively, by any child `Component` of those `Windows` that
>   has no such `Set` of its own explicitly defined.

If you yet want to do this change I'd suggest you use [JComponent.getInputMap()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getInputMap%28%29) and [JComponent.getActionMap()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getActionMap%28%29) instead. For instance:

```
AbstractAction action = new AbstractAction() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource() instanceof JButton){
            JButton button = (JButton) e.getSource();
            button.doClick();                
        } else if(e.getSource() instanceof JComponent){
            JComponent component = (JComponent) e.getSource();
            component.transferFocus();
        }
    }
};

JTextField textField1 = new JTextField();
textField1.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0), "TransferFocus");
textField1.getActionMap().put("TransferFocus", action);

JTextField textField2 = new JTextField();
textField2.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0), "TransferFocus");
textField2.getActionMap().put("TransferFocus", action);

JButton button1= new JButton();
button1.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0), "Enter");
button1.getActionMap().put("Enter", action);
```

This way you'll need to set the action for each component you want. It's tedious if you have too many components **but** it's more flexible and maintainable.

Comment: yes, that's work. but, how if the focus on Jbutton?? is it possible to do click the jbutton if we Type Enter too??

Comment: @afzalur yes it is. Take a look to updated answer. You still need to add an `ActionListener` to your `JButton` which is the responsible for doing something when the button is pressed. Then if `Enter` key is pressed, `button.doClick()` will do the trick.